# Multiply the value by decimal number in latex?

Tags: calculations

I used the following construct quite often:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth/2]{pic.png}
```

But when I try to adjust the size a small bit, like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*0.45]{pic.png}
```

I get

```
! Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `calc` package allows only division by integers or by reals which are announced as `\real`: so

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*\real{0.45}]{pic}
```

will do, but

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic}
```

works as well, doesn't require `calc` and is faster.

Comment: Thanks! I really should read a bit about TeX syntax - because this was not very obvious.

Answer (score 17):

You can use

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic.png}
```

Answer (score 9):

Great "short" answers!

Just to expand into the general concept that will answer this question in a more understandable way:

Wherever you have **a macro that expands into a length** for instance: `\parskip`, `\linewidth`, ... Or in this case `\textwidth` you can create another length just by setting a **floating point factor** before the macro.

For example:

- `0.78\parskip`
- `2\linewidth`
- ...

or in your case
`0.45\textwidth`

are valid values for the parameter `width` in `includegraphics`

You can take a look at the first lines of the wiki article:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths