# Adjust \lxvchars etc. for \documentclass point size

Tags: memoir, fontsize, fontspec

Follow-up to [query re: adjusting textheight in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52957/multiply-the-value-by-decimal-number-in-latex?rq=1)

Apparently, memoir's `\setlxvchars[\normalfont]\setxlvchars[\normalfont]` commands standardize the result to 10pt, regardless of the point size specified in `\documentclass`. How can one adjust for this? Minimal example follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}

\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\psize}{\f@size}
\makeatother
\setlxvchars[\normalfont]
\setxlvchars[\normalfont]
\begin{document}
Point size = \psize\par
L45 = \the\xlvchars\par
L65 = \the\lxvchars
\end{document}
```

L45 and L65 only seem to change as the font is changed. I've tried unsuccessfully to adjust for the ratio `\psize` : 10. Shouldn't be that hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No explanation, but at least a workaround: Add `\normalsize` to the arguments of `\setlxvchars` and `\setxlvchars`. (Strange enough, `\normalsize` is only necessary if `fontspec` is loaded.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\psize}{\f@size}
\makeatother

\setlxvchars[\normalfont\normalsize]
\setxlvchars[\normalfont\normalsize]

\begin{document}

Point size = \psize\par
L45 = \the\xlvchars\par
L65 = \the\lxvchars

\end{document}
```

[image]

Output for `10pt` class option:

[image]

Comment: I think it's part of the way `fontspec` works, slightly different from the "traditional" way. If you try `\showthe\font` in the preamble (with `fontspec`), you'll get 10pt size no matter what size option you set.