# Simple way to multiply two values

Tags: calculations

I have a macro to define the scale of my figures:

```
\newcommand{\myscale}{0.35}
```

Now I have a figure that needs to be scaled twice as big, so I tried to use something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \includegraphics[scale=2\myscale]{my-image}
  \caption{My Caption}
  \label{fig:my-label}
\end{figure}
```

This results a very big image, as `2\scale` expands to `20.35`...

I tried/found:

- Using `scale=2*\myscale`, but still get errors
- [Some more things using `calc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/how-to-do-simple-calculation-in-latex/87827#87827), again did not work
- [`\real{}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52957/multiply-the-value-by-decimal-number-in-latex/52959#52959), but it does not seem to work also
- [intcalc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34424/how-do-i-calculate-n-modulo-3-in-latex/34426#34426), but this only seems to work for integers, which is not always the case for `\myscale`.
- [pgf package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/how-to-do-simple-calculation-in-latex/87826#87826), but it seems a complex for a simple multiplication
- [fp package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/how-to-do-simple-calculation-in-latex/87825#87825) works, but still somewhat complex

The easiest way (that works for me), is this fp-based implementation:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \FPeval\calculatedScale{2*\myscale}
  \includegraphics[scale=\calculatedScale]{my-image}
  \caption{My Caption}
  \label{fig:my-label}
\end{figure}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a more simple/elegant solution? Preferably directly usable with the `\includegraphics` command without creating the additional `\calculatedScale`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `l3fp` package allows expandable calculations with floating point numbers.  Expandability means that you don't need to store the result in a temporary variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % 

%%%%
% Provide the command \fpeval as a copy of the code-level \fp_eval:n.
\usepackage{expl3}[2012-07-08]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myscale}{0.53}
\includegraphics[scale=\fpeval{2*\myscale}]{your-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example give this error: `Runaway argument?   scale=\fpeval {2*\myscale }]{your-image} \end {document}   ! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.`. Is there anything that might went wrong with the `\fpeval{}` command?

Comment: @Veger You need the `graphicx` package for keyval syntax: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had not tested appropriately.

Comment: It helps a bit, as I get loads of new errors like `Undefined control sequence`, `Missing number, treated as zero` and `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`. With `scale=0.7` all errors disappear. Is there another problem with the syntax?

Comment: @Veger: your `expl3` is too old, it does not have `\fp_eval:n`.

Comment: I updated texlive to version 20130520 (from Ubuntu saucy-proposed) and now it all works, thanks for your nice solution and your help!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe simply (second version is with the scaling):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{it}

\scalebox{2}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{it}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed also a possibility! Although it seems redundant to use two scales/commands. Are there any drawbacks to this method?

Answer (score 0):

Bruno's answer above was super helpful, thanks for that. I didn't even know about this facility in latex3 and was trying to use pgfmath operations which was not working.

Here is an overleaf project https://www.overleaf.com/read/kbbhfkpywfnp that has sample of making this table chart[image: bar chart]

The latex for this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% makes a table with bars that scale to desired maximum percent or degrees values

% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115558/simple-way-to-multiply-two-values
%%%%
% Provide the command \fpeval as a copy of the code-level \fp_eval:n.
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\barwidth}{10} % cm
\newcommand{\percentscale}{100} % max scale for percent bars
\newcommand{\degscale}{90} % max scale for degree bars

\def\pcbar#1{%%
  #1s\% & {\color{red}\rule{\fpeval{#1/\percentscale*\barwidth} cm}{8pt}}%
}
\def\degbar#1{%%
  #1s$^\circ$ & {\color{red}\rule{\fpeval{#1/\degscale*\barwidth} cm}{8pt}}%
}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 \pcbar{90}\\
 \pcbar{60}\\
 \pcbar{30}\\

\degbar{10}\\
\degbar{50}\\
\degbar{89}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can simply do `\usepackage{xfp}` that provides `\fpeval`.

Comment: Thanks!  This is much better and more understandable. Hopefully supported by journal submission tex installations. I updated the overleaf project linked above.