# How to use bar chart to represent percentage in table?

Tags: tables, bar-chart, percentage

I want to use black and gray bar to represent some percentages. Gray is the basic color on bottom,the black is the real percentage. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Intresting question. What have you done so far? Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\MAX` defines the maximal width of the bar, which is 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newlength\MAX  \setlength\MAX{5mm}
\newcommand*\Chart[1]{#1~\rlap{\textcolor{black!20}{\rule{\MAX}{2ex}}}\rule{#1\MAX}{2ex}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l @{}}
Pull Up Method & \Chart{1.000} & \Chart{0.600}\\
Move Field     & \Chart{0.269} & \Chart{0.783}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to change the height of the bar to the height of the characters.

Answer (score 3):

Alternativly you could create a single bar like this: [Is it possible to create a barchart in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173101/124842).
With `\usepackage{calc}` you could compute the differnce between the max value (defined with `\newlength\WIDTHOFBAR` and `\setlength\WIDTHOFBAR{1cm}`) to get the percentages representation with the following definiton.

*Bar chart definition:*

```
\def\blackwhitebar#1{%%
  #1 {\color{black!100}\rule{#1cm}{8pt}}{\color{black!30}\rule{\WIDTHOFBAR - #1 cm}{8pt}}}
```

**Solution:**

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\WIDTHOFBAR
\setlength\WIDTHOFBAR{1cm}

\def\blackwhitebar#1{%%
  #1 {\color{black!100}\rule{#1cm}{8pt}}{\color{black!30}\rule{\WIDTHOFBAR - #1 cm}{8pt}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ l r r r r r } 
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}\\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
            Type & Precision & Recall  & Precision & Recall \\\midrule
            Move Type & \blackwhitebar{1.000}  &\blackwhitebar{0.968} & ... & ... \\
            Extract Type & \blackwhitebar{1.000}  &\blackwhitebar{0.600} & ... & . \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have finished the table , it's very cool

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using tikz:

```
\documentclass{article} 


\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\DrawPercentageBar}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=black]   (0.0 , 0.0) rectangle (#1*3ex , 1.5ex );
    \fill[color=gray] (#1*3ex  , 0.0) rectangle (3.0ex, 1.5ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

0.800 \DrawPercentageBar{0.8}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result:[image]

You could also change the dimension of the bar depending on your needs.

Comment: You shoulkd use `\newcommand{\DrawPercentageBar}[1]{%` and also `\end{tikzpicture}%`. Then you do not get additional spaces in the output.