# Do multiplication rules differ in TikZ compared to standard TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I'd like to scale a line according to `\figscale`. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52957/multiply-the-value-by-decimal-number-in-latex) it is said that the below syntax should work in general, but in this graphic it does not.

As the picture shows, the numbers are just concatenated to, e.g., `-0.53cm` instead of `-0.5 * 3cm = 1.5cm`, although I'd like to multiply them. Writing `-0.5*\figscale`works well.

*Why is the solution provided in the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52957/multiply-the-value-by-decimal-number-in-latex) not applicable here?*

```
\def \figscale{3cm}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-1.0,2) -- (0,2) node[midway, anchor=south] {$A$};
        \draw (-0.5\figscale,1) -- (0,1) node[midway, anchor=south] {$B$};
        \draw (-1.0\figscale,0) -- (0,0) node[midway, anchor=south] {$C$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: `\def \figscale{3cm}` defines a macro that is simply replaced by `3cm` where used, it's not a length. Try `\newlength\figscale \setlength\figscale{3cm}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the answers to the linked question, `\textwidth` is used, which is a length parameter for TeX, so the syntax rules allow `4\textwidth` (or any decimal number instead of 4).

When TeX is looking for a length, it expands tokens as it goes. Since it expects a length and it has seen `-0.5` it expands the next token which might result in something that continues the decimal digits or something that begins with a length register. Your case is the former, because `\figscale` expands to `3cm` and

```
-0.53cm
```

is a perfect length specification for TeX. The situation is a bit more complicated because we're in the middle of a coordinate for TikZ and this explains why `-0.5*\figscale` works.

If you want a macro that behaves like a dimension, use

```
\newcommand{\figscale}{\dimexpr3cm\relax}
```

because TeX translates `\dimexpr3cm\relax` into a (nameless) internal length register. Nonetheless, you're probably best served with

```
\newlength{\figscale}
\setlength{\figscale}{3cm}
```

Answer (score 8):

Prefixing a "variable" with a number, for example, `4\textwidth` *only* works if the variable is a `TeX` dimension or skip or box dimension. This is consistent with usual `TeX` behaviour.

As the latest PGF manual states (section 88.1 "Commands for Parsing Expressions")

> The parser will recognize TEX registers and box dimensions, so \mydimen, 0.5\mydimen, \wd\mybox, 0.5\dp\mybox, \mycount\mydimen and so on can be parsed

The math parser expands every expression with `\edef` *before* parsing, so the MWE given above, `-0.5\figscale` becomes `-0.53cm` which is evaluated as `-15.07993` (points) as opposed to the desired `-42.67912`.